# How to execute a simple jQuery Program?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have created a simple jQuery program.i am new to jQuery technology..please provide me where am i wrong?

```
     <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd"
      >
 <html lang="en">
<head>
<title><!-- Insert your title here --></title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.2.min.js">
     $(document).ready(function() {
      alert("jQuery tutorial for beginners Example");
       });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p> i m here hid me</p>
<!-- Insert your content here -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should find a newer tutorial. jQuery 1.4.2 is very old.

Comment: Look on https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide

Answer (score 4):

The script you've written isn't supposed to go inside the jquery script tag. It needs to go in its own one.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
      alert("jQuery tutorial for beginners Example");
       });
</script>
```

The first one is to load jquery itself - it's like saying "instead of me writing some javascript here, load it from this file instead", the second one is for your own code since you've put code between the script tags.

Comment: Note that this isn't just a jquery thing. Script elements in general should specify a `src` _or_ have JS content, but not both.

Comment: thanks for suggestion..now my code is working..i was doing a bit mistake.

Answer (score 0):

A script element can have *one script*. That script can go between the start tag and the end tag **or** it can go in another file and be referenced with a src attribute.

If there is a src attribute, then the content of the element will be ignored.

If you want two scripts, then you need two script elements.

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
    // Your code
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Example: [Jsdiffle](http://jsfiddle.net/CYaJM/1/)

This is a example with last library of Jquery.

```
        <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd"
          >
     <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <title><!-- Insert your title here --></title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.0.js"></script>

       <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function() {
          alert("jQuery tutorial for beginners Example");
           });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <p> i m here hid me</p>
    <!-- Insert your content here -->
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: _"with last library of Jquery"_ - Have they gone out of business?

Comment: Are you suggesting that the reason the code wasn't working was because it was using jQuery 1.4 and not using jQuery UI?

Comment: Upgrade the libraries, such as updating programs
https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide

Comment: I also added the library Jquery-ui because the user is new.
And the tools 's Jquery-ui without declared the library 's Jquery, do not work well